# How to copy text from a file to a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, file

I have a couple of files inside a folder that I am trying to pull out text from, reason being that I eventually want to add this text into a newly created separate file. My tactic is to initialize a list and populate it with the text from each file, one by one. I have called this list `myLines`.

```
myLines = []

 for line in f:
        myLines.append(line)
    for element in myLines:
        f.write(myLines)
```

I get an error, and I know that it has something to do with `.write()` not accepting `myLines` because its a list rather than an argument. How would I go about turning the content of `mylines` into an acceptable argument for the `write()` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IDK what's your intention of using `myLines` as the variable name. Given what you described it should be a list of texts, not a list of lines.

```
my_texts = []

# populate my_texts
for filename in input_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        my_texts.append(f.read())

# write new file
with open('new_file_path.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(my_texts))
```

assuming you want a new line separating texts from each file.

A more straightforward method would be to 1) open the output file in append mode (`open('out_file_path', 'a')`), and 2) read each input file in a loop, writing the content to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    myLines = []

     for line in f:
            myLines.append(line)
        for element in myLines:
            f.write(str(myLines))
```

Just convert myLines to string. You can use classes also if you want to preserve the type- list, but, that will be a bit lengthy.